# Check if any row value in a pandas dataframe is present in file contents in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, list

I have a dataframe named df that has an ID column with several rows. I am reading in a file and want to quickly check if any of the IDs in the ID column of my dataframe are in the file contents. Below is what I'm currently doing. It works but I am sure there is a more efficient method for checking whether any row in a dataframe column exists in a file.

```
    # Read in and store file contents
    file = open('myfile.txt', 'r')
    contents = file.read()

    # Loop through each ID in the ID column and look for it in the file
    for id in df['ID']:
        if id in contents:
            print(f"found {id}")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps `df.isin()` (docs [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)) would be useful? You can then a new column that's a boolean mask of whether each ID is in the file.

```
df["id_found"] = df['ID'].isin(contents)
```

EDIT: Given that `contents` is a string, you can instead use a lambda function in conjunction with `df.apply` like this:

```
df["id_found"] = df.apply(lambda df: df['ID'] in contents, axis=1)
```

You can then view the IDs that are found by applying the mask

```
print(df["ID"][df["id_found"]])
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Tried this and isin() requires a list-like object to be passed, and my contents variable is a string.

Comment: Ah okay gotcha, in that case I've editted the response to account for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed! As mentioned that you want to see whether ANY ID is included, that means that if there is ONE occurrence, you need an indication.
You can use the following code:

```
with open('myfile.txt', 'r') as file:
contents = file.read()

if (df['ID'].isin(contents)).any():
    print("Found at least one matching ID")
```